# Can BO dashboard be created from WebI report?

Tags: business-objects, webi

I need to create a dashboard using my webi report. Can this be achievable? If so, how?

Thanks in Advance

Niki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this a few months back, while we primarily create Desktop Intelligence reports we have started to create WebI reports with the aim of creating dashboards with some of them.

We are running BOE XI3.1.

[Here](http://blog.davidg.com.au/2011/03/drill-down-in-xcelsius-using-bi.html) is a link to a blog which is one of the couple of blogs that I read when doing it.

Basically, you would right-click on the table in WebI and select publish block, you then follow the publish content prompts and when completed in the Web Services pane (if not visible, there is a Web Services checkbox in the top-right of the window) where you can get the Web Service URL that you can then use as a datasource within Xcelsius.

The WebI report I was playing with worked and I was able to get the data in Xcelsius.